# Combing two FITS tables on a single column entry using Python

Tags: python, join, datatables, fits

I read in two .FITS tables and place them into "list_a" and "list_b". List_b is a subset of List_a, but has some additional e.g. "age"',  that I'd like to add to my output. This is the current way I'm doing things:

```
file = open("MyFile.txt","w+") 

for ii in range(100000):
    name         = list_B[np.where((list_A['NAME'][ii] == list_B['NAME']))]['NAME']
    thing_from_b = list_B[np.where((list_A['NAME'][ii]  == list_B['NAME']))]['AGE']

    if (len(name) > 0) :
        file.write(" {} {} \n".format(list_A['NAME'][ii], age )

file.close()
```

but is so slow and clunky, that I'm sure there must be a better, more pythonic method.

Comment: check out `pandas` since it looks like you are looking to do a traditional join

Comment: What are `list_A` and `list_B`.  You didn't specify that.  I'm not sure where FITS comes in here unless those are columns from a FITS table, but if you're using the Astropy Table interface by that point it doesn't really matter where the table came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out turning the lists into DataFrames and then doing a `pandas` merge, does work very well::

```
from   pandas import DataFrame
from astropy.table import Table

list_a_table = Table(list_a)
list_a_df    = DataFrame(np.array(list_a_table))
list_b_table = Table(list_b)
list_b_df    = DataFrame(np.array(list_b_table))

df_merge = pd.merge(list_a_df, list_b_df, on="name")
```

Comment: Here you're just using `list_a` (where in your question you wrote `list_A`) and you're not using `list_B` at all so it's not clear how this solves the problem as you stated it (in particular you can't instantiate an Astropy `Table` from a single `list`, so what *actually* is `list_a`?  Without knowing what `list_a` is it's hard to tell what you're doing here.  Also there is a lot of needless copying going on here.  With Astropy's `Table` did you know you can call `.to_pandas()` to convert it to a pandas `DataFrame`?

Comment: (Note: I agree with the general approach of using pandas to join two tables, but I wanted to point out that this is not a clear answer for future readers)

Answer (score 0):

Assume "List_a" and "List_b" are both tables, and that you want to get the "ages" from "List_b" for entries where both "List_a" and "List_b", you can use Pandas as in your approach.  But Astropy also has a built-in [`join` operation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#join) for tables.

So I'm guessing you have something akin to:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> tab_a = Table({'NAME': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
>>> tab_b = Table({'NAME': ['A', 'C', 'D'], 'AGE': [1, 3, 4]})
```

If you are reading from a FITS file you can use, for example [`Table.read`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html#getting-started-with-table-i-o) to read a FITS table into a `Table` object (among other approaches).

Then you can use `join` to join the two tables where their name is the same:

```
>>> from astropy.table import join
>>> tab_c = join(tab_a, tab_b, keys='NAME')
>>> tab_c
<Table length=2>
NAME  AGE
str1 int64
---- -----
   A     1
   C     3
```

I think that maybe be what you're asking.

You could then write this out to a an ASCII format (similar to in your example) like:

```
>>> import sys
>>> tab_c.write(sys.stdout, format='ascii.no_header')
A 1
C 3
```

(Here you could replace `sys.stdout` with a filename; I was just using it for demonstration purposes).  As you can see there are many [built-in output formats for Tables](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html#built-in-table-readers-writers), though you can also define your own.

There are lots of goodies like this already in Astropy that should save you in many cases from reinventing the wheel when it comes to table manipulation and file format handling--just peruse the docs to get a better feel :)